# How does np.column_stack work? I am obtaining strange outputs for different examples

Tags: numpy

np.column_stack is quite strange in terms of output.
These are two examples I found on the internet->

```
1.    

import numpy as geek 

# input array 
in_arr1 = geek.array(( 1, 2, 3 )) 
print ("1st Input array : \n", in_arr1)  

in_arr2 = geek.array(( 4, 5, 6 )) 
print ("2nd Input array : \n", in_arr2)  

# Stacking the two arrays  
out_arr = geek.column_stack((in_arr1, in_arr2)) 
print ("Output stacked array:\n ", out_arr) 



Output:
1st Input array : 
 [1 2 3]
2nd Input array : 
 [4 5 6]
Output stacked array:
  [[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]]

2.
import numpy as geek 

 # input array 
in_arr1 = geek.array([[ 1, 2, 3], [ -1, -2, -3]] ) 
print ("1st Input array : \n", in_arr1)  

in_arr2 = geek.array([[ 4, 5, 6], [ -4, -5, -6]] ) 
print ("2nd Input array : \n", in_arr2)  

# Stacking the two arrays  
out_arr = geek.column_stack((in_arr1, in_arr2)) 
print ("Output stacked array :\n ", out_arr) 
Output:
1st Input array : 
 [[ 1  2  3]
 [-1 -2 -3]]
2nd Input array : 
 [[ 4  5  6]
 [-4 -5 -6]]
Output stacked array :
  [[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6]]
```

The eventual arrangement is different in both outputs? Can anyone explain?
Both the outputs are quite different in terms of arrangement

Comment: Your examples are consistent with the documentation.  2d arrays are joined as is on the 2nd dimension; 1d are turned into 'column vectors' and then joined.  The function is written in Python so you can read it yourself.  Like all the `stack` functions, it tweaks the input dimensions and then uses `np.concatenate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't know how to find the code for a numpy function like this, here it is:

```
def column_stack(tup):
    arrays = []
    for v in tup:
        arr = array(v, copy=False, subok=True)
        if arr.ndim < 2:
            arr = array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
        arrays.append(arr)
    return _nx.concatenate(arrays, 1)
```

It's that `v` loop that converts 1d inputs into 2d; the last `concatenate` line does the work.